# make build-list start from a specific point

Tags: scheme, racket

So I am learning to use buid-list

so I wrote a function :

```
(define (count-from n k)
(filter (lambda (n) (not(zero? n))) (build-list  k (lambda (n) (add1 n)))))
```

conventionally build-list starts from 0, I figured out how to exclude the zero,
but what I am stuck on is how can I make build-list start from a specific point 
like (count-from 7 10) to produce (list 7 8 9 10) and not start from 1.

note : I do not want to use any recursion or helper functions...I want to know if I can achieve what I seek simply from build-list and lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution can be written, like this:

```
(define (count-from n k)
  (build-list (add1 (- k n))
              (lambda (i) (+ i n))))
```

For example:

```
(count-from 7 10)
=> '(7 8 9 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure it out, so for anyone else wondering, this is what I did :

```
(define (count-from n k)
 (filter (lambda (y) (>= y n)) (filter (lambda (n) (not(zero? n))) 
   (build-list k (lambda (n) (add1 n))))))
```